# Aptana (eclipse) - While editing Python, enable camel case cursor movement

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana

I'm using Aptana to edit my python project.

I'm wondering if there's an option to define the editor to move *within* camel-cased words when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button is pressed.

E.g if my cursor is represented by a pipe '|' and is located here :

```
whatIsTheMeaningOfLife|
```

When pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left Arrow</kbd>
I want it to jump here :

```
whatIsTheMeaningOf|Life
```

And not before the first 'w'.

I'm pretty sure it should be somewhere under : *Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor*

But couldn't find it.

Thanks!